# Which design pattern is best for defining multiple data converters based on some condition?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles, clean-architecture

I have a use case where I need to define and call different RequestPreparationManagers based on some condition. Let's say that condition is the team name(I'm creating an umbrella framework which will be consumed by multiple teams in my Org) for which the manager needs to be called. My question is which design pattern is best for this scenario? I'm confused between the two design patterns which I think can be used here - Factory design pattern and Strategy design pattern. But I'm not able to decide which one of these two(or anything other design pattern which can be suitable for this scenario) is the best in respect to best Object Oriented Design practices.

I've written a very basic class definitions for how the actual implementation will look like using factory and strategy design patterns :

```
// Common classes and interfaces

public interface RequestPreparationManager
{
    InputRequest prepareInputRequest(Map<String, Object> params);
}

public class MarvelRequestPreparationManager implements RequestPreparationManager
{
    @Override
    public InputRequest prepareInputRequest(Map<String, Object> params)
    {
        // Some Logic
    }
}

public class DCRequestPreparationManager implements RequestPreparationManager
{
    @Override
    public InputRequest prepareInputRequest(Map<String, Object> params)
    {
        // Some Logic
    }
}

// Factory Design Pattern

public class RequestPreparationManagerFactory
{
    public static RequestPreparationManager getManager(String teamName)
    {
        switch(teamName)
        { 
            case "Marvel" : 
                return new MarvelRequestPreparationManager();
            case "DC" : 
                return new DCRequestPreparationManager();
            case default : 
                throw new UnsupportedTypeException();
        }
    }
}

public class Driver
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        InputRequest request = RequestPreparationManagerFactory.getManager("Marvel").prepareInputRequest(params);
    }
}

// Strategy Design Pattern

public class RequestPreparationManagerStrategy
{
    private Map<String, Object> params;

    public RequestPreparationManagerStrategy(Map<String, Object> params)
    {
        this.params = params;
    }

    public InputRequest prepareInputRequest(RequestPreparationManager requestPreparationManager)
    {
        return requestPreparationManager.prepareInputRequest(params);
    }
}

public class Driver
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        RequestPreparationManagerStrategy strategy = new RequestPreparationManagerStrategy(params);
        InputRequest request = strategy.prepareInputRequest(new MarvelRequestPreparationManager());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion will be to go with **event-driven architecture**. And since you are writing in java, I guess you will be using spring in some form.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events

Spring events are easy to maintain, are code readable and flexible to adapt to your needs.

Let me know if this helps in your case.

Comment: I didn't get how is spring events relevant to my use case? There is no requirement for publishing or listening any event. I just have to define 3-4 different classes which will prepare a request for some API and the invocation of the actual class will be decided on runtime on the basis of some condition.

Answer (score 0):

To me, your [strategy pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy) example does not make much sense at all as it does not really define a behavior. With a strategy pattern you'd probably have a generic user or manager class that you configure with a certain default strategy that may be updated during app configuration or at runtime that changes the behavior the user/manager is evaluating the input values. The point here is, the user/manager blindly invokes the strategy not knowing what concrete strategy it is performing and it couldn't actually care less either.

A typical scenario is when you need to calculate certain numbers differently based on the role of the user. Instead of hard-wiring the logic into the user, you abstract away the calculation into behavior classes (=strategies) which you then attach to the respective user. Upon performing some operation on that user the strategy internally is invoked to execute the calculation. Note that the user itself is generic, so you don't subclass the user here actually. Think of a game engine that rewards a player with XP and based on the subscription model the user signed up to, s/he is now rewarded with different XP. A free-user might receive 80% of the XP while a regular user might receive 100% and a VIP 125% XP. While you may create a class *FreeUser*, *RegularUser* and *VIPUser* that are based on a common *User*  class, you probably need to implement much more if during a bonus-weekend you introduce the class of *TrialUser* or the like instead of just defining how its XP is rewarded differently.

> ... I need to define and call different RequestPreparationManagers based on some condition

This sounds like you are already describing the purpose of a creation pattern such as a [factory pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method) or a configured [builder pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder). Here, usually based on the availability of certain data, a decision is taken which concrete product needs to be created (or reused) and returned.